# Create object with key => value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im' trying to create an object in a loop which contain `key => [value]`, if key exist, add the value.

I tried like this :

```js
let dataName = [];
let obj = {};

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            obj[name] = [checkbox.id]
            dataName.push(obj);
        }
    });
```

And when I click the value is override instead being added. How to add value by keys when the checkbox is checked ?

Comment: `obj[name]` should be `obj[checkbox.name]` ?

Comment: What is `checkboxes`? Where is your minimal HTML?

Comment: Why are you pushing the same object multiple times into the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new object for each iteration

```
checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            let obj = {};
            obj[name] = [checkbox.id]
            dataName.push(obj);
        }
    });
```

Also, if `obj[name]` is not working, try `obj[checkbox.getAttribute("name")] = ...;`

Also, you can select only checked checkboxes using

```
document.querySelectorAll("input:checked");
```